# Postgresql Operational Error

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, web.py

I am a beginner for web.py and working on the web.py tutorial form section. I came across the code in form library for a simple signup. http://webpy.org/form and the upgrades for web.py0.3 http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/upgrade

I am trying to write a form for signup of username and pwd , I installed pyscopg2 and postgres2.6.1 and others they have recommended in tutorial using pip.
I wrote the following code in practice/bin/code.py

```
import web 
from web import form


urls = (
       '/' , 'index'
        )
app = web.application(urls , globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/')

signup = form.Form(
        form.Textbox('Username'),
        form.Password('Password'),
        form.Password('Password_Again'),
        validators = [form.Validator('Passwords did not match' , lambda i: i.Password == i.Password_Again)]
)

class index(object):

    def GET(self):
        form = signup()
        return render.formtest(form = form)



    def POST(self):
        form = signup()
        if not form.validates():
            return render.formtest(form = form)

        else:
            db = web.database(dbn='postgres', db='test' ,host="127.0.0.1" ,user='richa9@gmail.com' ,password='123',port='5432')
            login= db.insert('test' , **form.d)
            return "Great success! you connected to your first database!"







if __name__ == "__main__" :
    web.internalerror = web.debugerror
    app.run()
```

And inside practice/templates/formtest.html

```
$def with (form)

<form name = "main" method = "POST">
$if not form.valid: <p class = "error"> Try Again! </p>

$:form.render()

<input type = "submit"/> 

</form>
```

I researched and read documents of web.py but since I am new to databases in apps I am stuck with the same error. When I run the code.py in cmd and it starts the 8080 server , I get this Traceback in cmd:

```
127.0.0.1:55677 - - [08/May/2016 13:02:53] "HTTP/1.1 POST /" - 500 Internal Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 239, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 230, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 420, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 396, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "C:\practice\bin\code.py", line 35, in POST
    login= db.insert('test' , **form.d)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\db.py", line 766, in insert
    db_cursor = self._db_cursor()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\db.py", line 566, in _db_cursor
    return self.ctx.db.cursor()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\db.py", line 507, in _getctx
    self._load_context(self._ctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\db.py", line 518, in _load_context
    ctx.db = self._connect(self.keywords)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\db.py", line 960, in _connect
    conn = DB._connect(self, keywords)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\db.py", line 546, in _connect
    return self.db_module.connect(**keywords)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The formtest.html responds when I put unmatched passwords ,but not the database system.Any suggestions to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `postgres2.6.1` - what exactly did you install here? There is no such version of postgresql. Please download the correct installer for your version of Windows [from this link](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows).

Comment: i guess that was psycopg2 version. I had downloaded this version before from the link you post , but its giving the same error again.

Comment: Once you download and ran the installer, did you make sure the server is actually started? Try restarting the machine (the server should start automatically at boot) or start it manually from the services section of the control panel.

Comment: should I be putting this downloaded file in python27/Lib/site-packages/ directory?

Comment: Which file? What you download is in an installer for the database _server_. You need to run it so it will setup a server for you.

Comment: okay...should the port be given 5432?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to setup a postgresql server on your host in order to complete the exercise.

As you are on Windows, you need to download the [windows installer](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows) and then [follow the documentation](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.5/instguide/Postgres_Plus_Advanced_Server_Installation_Guide.1.19.html#pID0E01WC0HA) on how to install the server.

Once you have installed the server, you need to create a login role and database and assign the role to the database before you can continue.

To do this, use the `pgadminIII` tool which is installed as part of the server; and follow these steps:

1. Expand the `Servers` tree under `Server Groups` on the left pane.
2. Double click on the server listed (should be PostgreSQL 9.5 (localhost:5432)). This connects you to the server. You need to use the password you set up in the installer.
3. Right click on `Login Roles`, and select `New Role..`
4. Fill in the Role name (this is the user's login name)
5. Enter two passwords.
6. Click OK.
7. Right click on `Databases`, and select `New Database..`
8. Give it a name
9. In the Owner field, enter the name you entered in Role name in step 4.
10. Click OK

Then, in your code you need to adjust this line:

```
db = web.database(dbn='postgres',
                  db='test', # replace
                  user='richa9@gmail.com', # replace
                  password='123', # replace
                  port='5432', host="127.0.0.1")
```

and change the appropriate values.

**IMPORTANT** - Even if you follow these instructions, your code may fail as you haven't created any tables in your database and you are trying to insert records. Check the web.py documentation to see what tables are required for the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will do.